# Php xpath get only the head

Tags: php

I want to use xPath to get only the contents of the head element.

```
//some curl request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
if (!$DOM->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $result)) {
    $errors = "";
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        $errors .= $error->message . "<br/>";
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
    print "libxml errors:<br>$errors";
    return;
}
$xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
$head = $xpath->query('//*["head"]')->item(0); // Any suggestions?
```

As stated in the title, I am using PHP to try and extract the contents of whatever is in head in curl. Any suggestions is welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to access the `head` tag?

Comment: I need everything between <head> and </head>

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not referring to the header response. Simply the contents of what is in <head>

Answer (score 0):

If your curl response is as expected and everything up until your XPath is good, then try:

```
$head = $xpath->query('/head/*');
foreach ($head as $headElement) {
    /* DO STUFF*/
}
```

You may also not need to add `<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>` to the beginning of the result.

Comment: $head = $xpath->query('/head/*');
var_dump($head);
foreach ($head as $headElement) {
    echo $headElement->textContent;
}

$head is still empty.

Comment: Have you made sure that `$result` is not empty? As in, it is not boolean and contains the XML string you assume it has.

Comment: $head = $xpath->query("//*['head']"); Works!

Comment: But it strips <script> and <style> and <meta> tags. Any idea why?

Comment: How are you outputting the results? You may want to check the documentation for [DOMXPath::query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

Comment: In a simple echo $head->textContent;

Comment: In that case, most if not all of head child tags are going to have a blank `textContent`. If you need to see the full HTML you can use [DOMDocument::saveXML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php), something like: `echo $DOM->saveXML($headElement);`